# Can Vehicle Tracking be done without using Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, web-applications, geolocation, location

My web application is intended to track a college shuttle on a predefined fixed route. There are certain pickup points on the route which are fixed. Through the web-app, the user should be able to get the estimated time of arrival of a college shuttle. For that, I would require the actual distance - along the route and the speed of the vehicle. The haversine formula for the shortest distance would not apply over here. 
However, My friend thought of a solution that is to plot points along the route at a fixed distance say 20 meters, and calculate the distance in relation to the points. For example-If Shuttle is at point 5 and the user is at point 10, then the distance between both of them would be computed as (10-5)*20 i.e 100 meters. This solution isn't highly accurate but it would work.
How would I determine the shuttle location with respect to the points? I have the live coordinates of the shuttle, the coordinates of all the points on the route. What is the best way to get the result such as 
`Shuttle location is point 5`. I am using Javascript and NodeJS. For Database MongoDB. Current location is obtained using Geolocation API

Answer (score 0):

Leaflet is a great platform for maps and there is a plugin for k-next-nearest-neighbor searches here https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-knn

The nearest stop along the route to the bus would then give you what you need I think